TypeScript unable to infer generic parameter default with optional argument?
I am trying to write a TypeScript function with a generic parameter default and optional arguments
function doSomething<T = number>(a?: T): T {
    if (a===undefined) return 5;
    return a;
}

After checking that a was not passed, I expect T to be assigned type number. However, TypeScript raises an error.
We can use as:
function doSomething<T = number>(a?: T): T {
    if (a===undefined) return 5 as T;
    return a;
}

but this is a bit redundant as then the default type is not needed. Moreover, using as  can lead to undetected type errors. This compiles without errors:
function doSomething<T = number>(a?: T): T {
    if (a===undefined) return "asdf" as T;
    return a;
}

Essentially, the only purpose of the default generic type here is for readability, and it still leaves room for undetected unwanted behavior.
Is there a way to make TypeScript infer the type of a generic when the argument assigning that type is optional?
Demonstration in TS playground: code

"Is there a way to make TypeScript infer the type of a generic when the argument assigning that type is optional?"  - If no argument is specified then there's no variable a from which TS can infer T - whereas if a is not specified then T is undefined. Remember that undefined is a type just like null is also a type. I know you have T = number but a: undefined will take precedence, methinks.

if( a === undefined ) { ... } should be if( typeof a === 'undefined' ) { ... }.


Actually your example doesn't have anything to do with the parameter being optional. The error just says that 5 is not always assignable to T. A passed argument a could be any other value as well, even a value that isn't a number. A default generic parameter is not the same thing as a generic constraint. 2. There are plenty of different use cases and examples on the internet. This is the first I can think of.


^ You can also check out the Github pull request regarding default generic parameters and the linkes issues for more examples.

Thanks all, I didn't realize you can pass the type T when calling the function. So the error is raised in the initial example to guard against something like doSomething<string>();

• Please [edit] this to ask a single primary question, or it risks being closed with "Needs more focus: This question currently includes multiple questions in one. It should focus on one problem only." • Assuming it's q1, you're looking for ms/TS#58977 and currently it's not part of the language. There are only workarounds, which I could elaborate on in an answer if you think this fully address the question.  If not, what am I missing?

I didn't realize you can pass the type into the generic when calling the function, so Typescript raises the error in the initial example to guard against something like doSomething<string>(). It seems the best solution is to just use as as in the second codeblock.
